# Detect Entering a Text between two TextPointer s in RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

i have RichTExtBox in my WPF program. imagine that i have 2 TextPointers which indicating the first and last of some part of the RTB. how can i know that if the entered Text is in between these two Pointers or not ?

```
//i have the values of these 3 pointer.imagine they are filled
    private bool isBetween(TextPointer first,TextPointer Last,TextPointer Current){
   //i don't know how to write this function
}
```

in the above code `First` and `Last` indicate the area ! and i want this function to tell me if is `Current` between these two TextPointers or not ?

Comment: please calrify what do you mean by  the last sentence about the event. Can you post the code?

Comment: just forget about last sentence :D i omit it :D

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing: when is it called? you have 5 different testpointers in your code and I cannot understand where their values come from. Is this code taken from a real, compiled code?

Comment: i want a function that takes 3 arguments !

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `TextRange` from 2 `TextPointers` and use the method `Contains`. It's fairly easy:

```
private bool isBetween(TextPointer first,TextPointer last,TextPointer current){
   return new TextRange(first, last).Contains(current);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
private bool isBetween(TextPointer first,TextPointer last,TextPointer current)
{
    bool isAfterFirst = first.GetOffsetToPosition(current) >= 0;
    bool isBeforeLast = last.GetOffsetToPosition(current) <= 0;

    return isAfterFirst && isBeforeLast;
}
```

add all null checks that you see appropriate...

based on:
[MSDN : GetOffsetToPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textpointer.getoffsettoposition(v=vs.110).aspx)